# What is the use of the return value in strrev()?

Tags: c

What is the use of return value of `strrev()`? Even after reversing the string, the value will be modified in the given string.

Ex: `char *strrev(char *src);` Here after the string is reversed, the output will be present in the src. In that case what is the use of returning the string?

Either the return value or the string which we are passing also acts as output, that is enough. In that case what is the use of return value of `strrev()`?

Comment: It allows chaining of string-manipulating calls

Comment: Spoiler: There is no _standard_ `strrev()`.

Comment: You could directly use the result for further processing as for example in `printf("%s\n", strrev(str));` or `do_more_stuff(strrev(str))`.

Comment: try writing a palindrome program using strrev and strcmp in minimum number of code lines. Thats' the only probable use I can think of. I don't even remember when I have reversed any string.

Answer (score 5):

To allow chaining.

Imagine you wanted to reverse a string, then reverse it back again (contrived example, but it makes the point). With chaining, you can do this:

```
strrev(strrev(charBuffer));
```

If `sttrev` returned `void`, you'd have to do:

```
strrev(charBuffer);
strrev(charBuffer);
```

to get the same result.

As @WernerHenze says in his comment, it also allows you to directly work with the output in function calls, like this:

```
printf("%s\n", strrev(charBuffer));
```

The possibility of chaining basically gives more flexibility to the programmer as to how the code is structured.

Answer (score 0):

Chaining makes more sense, but it can also be used in an unlikely micro-optimisation.  You can avoid saving a temporary value on the stack during the call.  Eg.:

```
char *fn(char *s) {
  strrev(s);
  strlwr(s);
  return strstr(s, "secret");
}
```

Over the calls to `strrev()` and `strlwr()` you need to keep a safe copy of `s` for subsequent use.  You can eliminate this register save using:

```
char *fn(char *s) {
  s = strrev(s);
  s = strlwr(s);
  return strstr(s, "secret");
}
```

As per the chaining answer, you could also use:

```
char *fn(char *s) {
  return strstr(strlwr(strrev(s)), "secret");
}
```

But that can be a problem in more complex code.

I just tried it and it eliminated three `mov` instructions.  Yay!!